# Is it decidable whether or not a collection of integer matrices generates a free group?

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, algorithms, gr.group-theory

Suppose we have integer matrices $A_1,\ldots,A_n\in\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb Z)$.  Define $\varphi:F_n\to\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb Z)$ by $x_i\mapsto A_i$.  Is there an algorithm to decide whether or not $\varphi$ is injective?

Comment: The corresponding problem for semigroups is undecidable for $n\geq 3$.  I don't know what is known for groups.  It is probably open and undecidable.

Comment: Benjamin - I'd be interested in a reference for the semi-group case, if you have one.

Comment: This was proved by Klarner, Birget and Satterfield in IJAC in 1991 for something like n=5 and improved to 3 and upper triangular in http://iml.univ-mrs.fr/~cassaign/publis/freeness.ps.gz

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For $n=1, 2$ the answer is "yes" since the group is virtually free, for $n\ge 3$ the answer is not known (an open problem).

**Edit.**  In fact even for two $n\times n$-matrices the problem is open. Moreover the solution of the following ``easier" problem is not known: for which algebraic integers $\lambda$ the matrices $\left(\begin{array}{ll} 1 & 2\\\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)$ and  $\left(\begin{array}{ll} 1 & 0\\\ \lambda & 1 \end{array}\right)$ generate a free group (see  [this](http://cage.ugent.be/~bamberg/Research_files/Non-free%20points%20for%20groups%20generated%20by%20a%20pair%20of%202x2%20matrices.pdf)  paper, for example). The fact that this problem is easier follows from the trivial observation that the group generated by these two matrices is isomorphic to some effectively computable group of $n\times n$-integer matrices for some $n\ge 2$ (depending on the degree of the algebraic number $\lambda$).

Comment: It's not clear for me that's it's easier. It might happen that for each n there's an algorithm in GL(n,Z) to detect free groups (as in the initial question) but that this algorithm does not depend recursively on n.

Comment: @Yves: The size of the matrices is the degree of the $\lambda$. There is currently no hope to resolve the problem even if the degree is 3.  

Answer (score 14):

Here are some general facts that may be relevant.

Given a finitely presented group $G$ and a representation $\rho:G\to GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$, [there is no algorithm](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=AUCN&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=bridson&s5=wilton&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=1&mx-pid=2782175) *which is uniform in $n$* that decides whether or not $\rho$ is injective.

However, this leaves open the possibility that there is such an algorithm for particular $n$.  (It's easy for $n=2$, when the group is virtually free. I believe nothing is known for $n>2$.)  Also, the examples we construct are not free groups, so it may be possible to say something in that case.

In another direction, given a finite presentation for a group $G$ *and a solution to the word problem in $G$*, [one can algorithmically determine](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=IID&s1=814406&vfpref=html&r=7&mx-pid=2516172) whether or not $G$ is a free group.

Answer (score 5):

Some comments on the question  'Is it decidable whether or not a
collection of integer matrices generates a free group?'

Given a finite set of matrices S over a field, the problem of
testing whether the group H generated by S contains a free
non-abelian subgroup is decidable. An algorithm solving the
problem as well as its implementation (in Magma) available. Notice
that the algorithms does not construct a free non-abelian subgroup
in H but justifies its existence. As to testing freeness of
finitely generated linear groups then the problem has quite a long
history. I may recommend as a start point the paper by John Dixon
Can.J Math, v. 37, n. 2, 1985, 238-259 (see p. 240 there, and then
follow the references).

Comment: I cannot find this paper! Do you have a link?